# Sort Javascript object by calculation on property values

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a *parent* item, positioned at **(0, 0)**. A *parent* item has *children*, whose positions are stored relative to the *parent*. For example, `children[2]`'s position is **(2, -8)**.

The *parent* can be moved, and when it does, it's net movement is stored in `movement`, `delta_x` and `delta_y`. In the first example, the *parent* is moving right: 1, and up: 0. We can say that this item is moving right. In the second example, the *parent* is moving right: 1, and up: -2. We can say that this item is moving down, since it's movement right is smaller than it's movement down.

I need to sort `children` so that if the *parent* is moving right, the *children* are sorted right to left. Below I've posted two scenarios and their expected outputs.

[image: Example image]

```
var children = {
    2: {
        relative_position_x: 2,
        relative_position_y: -4
    }, // Positioned at (2, -4)
    4: {
        relative_position_x: 0,
        relative_position_y: -3
    }, // Positioned at (0, -3)
    1: {
        relative_position_x: 2,
        relative_position_y: 0
    } // Positioned at (2, 0)
}; // Relative to (0, 0)

var movement = {
    delta_x: 1,
    delta_y: 0
}; // Item is moving east (right)

// Another possible scenario, expecting output to be [2, 4, 1]
// var movement = {
//     delta_x: 1,
//     delta_y: -2
// }; // Item is moving south (forget about (east) delta_x because it's a smaller movement than delta_y)

console.log(sortedChildren); // expected [1, 2, 4] or [2, 1, 4] (from right-left)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will support everything unless the item is going diagonally (delta_x and delta_y have the same value), i'm still unsure of how to sort this instance.

```
var children = {
    2: {
        relative_position_x: 2,
        relative_position_y: -4
    }, // Positioned at (2, -4)
    4: {
        relative_position_x: 0,
        relative_position_y: -3
    }, // Positioned at (0, -3)
    1: {
        relative_position_x: 2,
        relative_position_y: 0
    } // Positioned at (2, 0)
}; // Relative to (0, 0)

var movement = {
    delta_x: 1,
    delta_y: 0
}; // Item is moving east (right)

var sortedChildren = [];

for (var childrenId in children) {
    if (Math.abs(movement.delta_x) == Math.abs(movement.delta_y)) {
        // diagonal
        console.log('Diagonal Movement: not supported');
    } else if (Math.abs(movement.delta_x) > Math.abs(movement.delta_y) && movement.delta_x > 0) {
        // right
        sortedChildren.push([children[childrenId], -children[childrenId].relative_position_x]);
    } else if (Math.abs(movement.delta_x) > Math.abs(movement.delta_y) && movement.delta_x < 0) {
        // left
        sortedChildren.push([children[childrenId], children[childrenId].relative_position_x]);
    } else if (Math.abs(movement.delta_x) < Math.abs(movement.delta_y) && movement.delta_y > 0) {
        // up
        sortedChildren.push([children[childrenId], -children[childrenId].relative_position_y]);
    } else if (Math.abs(movement.delta_x) < Math.abs(movement.delta_y) && movement.delta_y < 0) {
        // down
        sortedChildren.push([children[childrenId], children[childrenId].relative_position_y]);
    }
}

sortedChildren.sort(
    function(a, b) {
        return a[1] - b[1];
    }
);

console.log(sortedChildren);
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohqc668f/)